# Every positive number has the unique square root

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

I have found the following proof in Rosenlicht's Introduction to Analysis. I don't quite get why $(y-\epsilon)^2 < a < (y+\epsilon)^2$. Could someone explain it to me? Thanks. Any shorter proof or graphical intuition is also very welcome.

[image]

Comment: Draw the graph of the function $x \mapsto x^2$ for $x\ge 0$. It is easy to see that it will take any value $a \ge 0$ (only once), which means there exists (a unique) an $x\ge0$ such that $x^2=a$.

Comment: Yes, I know... But this is elementary proof, not having even defined continuity or a function. You can only use properties of a field, total order, and l.u.b. in the proof

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- "There are numbers greater than $y-\epsilon$ in $S$" means that there exists $x\in S$ such that $y-\epsilon < x$ and so $(y-\epsilon)^2 < x^2 < a$, because $x \in S$.
- $y+\epsilon\notin S$ implies $(y+\epsilon)^2 > a$ by definition of $S$.

Comment: So clear, thank you very much.